# How to log two values based on click and set a new function to act upon it

Tags: javascript, html, web, timer

I have a function that creates a timer, then returns a string value to the DOM and updates it live (by millisecond) in the browser. I would like to get the the **current time** value from that object whenever a link is clicked, then **set a timeout function** to countdown from that time, but the function be relevant to whichever link is clicked.

How would I go about doing this with the code I have below?

```js
let parentNode = document.querySelector('.time-options');
parentNode.addEventListener("click", logLinkId, false);

function logLinkId(e) {
 if (e.target !== e.target.id) { 
  let clickedHour = e.target.id;
  alert('timer is set for ' + `${clickedHour}!`);
 }
 e.stopPropagation();
}


function currentTime() {
 let date = new Date();
 let hour = date.getHours();
 let min = date.getMinutes();
 let sec = date.getSeconds();
 let midday = "AM";
 midday = (hour >= 12) ? "PM" : "AM";
 hour = (hour == 0) ? 12 : ((hour > 12) ? (hour - 12) : hour);


 hour = updateTime(hour);
 min = updateTime(min);
 sec = updateTime(sec);
 document.getElementById("clock").textContent =
  `${hour} : ${min} : ${sec}`;
 var t = setTimeout(function () { currentTime() }, 1000);


 document.getElementById("clock").innerText = `${hour} : ${min} : ${sec} ${midday}`; /* adding time to the div */
 var t = setTimeout(currentTime, 1000); /* setting timer */
}

function updateTime(k) { /* appending 0 before time elements if less than 10 */
 if (k < 10) {
  return "0" + k;
 }
 else {
  return k;
 }
}
currentTime();
```

```css
.time-options {
 border: 2px solid blue;
 padding: 0.15rem;

}
.time-options a {
 display: inline-flex;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #e20000;
 display: inline-block;
}

.time-options span {
 cursor: default;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.time-options a:hover {
 color: blue;
}

/* dropdown menu */
.dropdown {
 margin: 10px 0;
 background: white;
 width: 200px;
 height: 30px;
 box-shadow: 6px 6px blue;

 line-height: 30px;
 user-select: none;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 1em;
 font-family: monospace;
 position: relative;
 left: 10px;
}

.dropdown:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: #999;
}

.dropdown_value {
 display: inline-block;
 padding-left: 5px;
}

.dropdown_arrow {
 position: absolute;
 right: 5px;
 top: 0px;
}

.dropdown_panel {
 position: absolute;
 background: transparent;
 width: calc(100% + 10px);
 z-index: 99999;
 height: 200px;
 left: -1px;
 top: 28px;
 overflow: hidden;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.dropdown_items {
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: all;
 top: 0px;
 width: calc(100% - 11px);
 max-height: 170px;
 background-color: white;
 box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #999;
 overflow-y: auto;
 border: 1px solid #aaa;
 transform: translate(0px, -200px);
 transition: 0.3s all ease-out;
}

.dropdown_item {
 padding: 1px;
 font-size: 20px;
}

.dropdown_item:hover {
 background: #eee;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown ::-webkit-scrollbar {
 width: 10px;
}

.dropdown ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
 background: blue;
}
```

```html
  <div class="sub-title">
   <div class="label-txt">currently:</div>
   <span id="clock" class="digi"></span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="time-options">
   <a href="#" id="hour">1 Hour</a> <span>⏰</span> <br />
   <a href="#" id="later">Later Today</a> <span></span> <br />
   <a href="#" id="evening">This Evening</a> <span></span><br />
   <a href="#" id="tmrw">Sometime Tomorrow</a> <span></span> <br />
  </div>
  <div id="dd1"></div>
```